# MULTIPLE IF ELSE CONDITION IN LOGSTASH WITH AND OPERATOR

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

if i use this logic in logstash it works

`if "a" in [msg] or "b" in [msg]`

but what i need to use is and conditioning. if i replace **or** with **and** then it would fail. Is there any idea?

This will fail

```
if "a" in [msg] and "b" in [msg]
```

What i want to do is whenever selected string a and b is there and use the filter as defined, Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, can you share a sample of your data so people can try to find what is wrong?

Comment: ya its  true, its already correct...My only mistake is about the string used which was should be A caps not small caps!..Thanks for the clarification @leandrojmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
filter {  
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:my_data}" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ "_failure", "_grokparsefailure" ]
  }

  if "sandeep" in [my_data] and "kanabar" in [my_data]{
    mutate {
      add_field => { "status" => "Both name and surname present"}
    }
  }
  else if "sandeep" in [my_data] or "kanabar" in [my_data]{
    mutate {
      add_field => { "status" => "either name/surname present"}
    }
  }
}
```

Output of test run:

```
Input --> name:"sandeep test"
Output:
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-10-31T11:27:33.941Z,
       "my_data" => "name:\"sandeep test\"",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "M22959216G3QD",
       "message" => "name:\"sandeep test\"",
        "status" => "either name/surname present"
}
Input --> :"test kanabar"
Output:
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-10-31T11:27:43.389Z,
       "my_data" => "name:\"test kanabar\"",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "my_host",
       "message" => "name:\"test kanabar\"",
        "status" => "either name/surname present"
}
Input --> :"sandeep kanabar"
Output:
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-10-31T11:27:50.516Z,
       "my_data" => "name:\"sandeep kanabar\"",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "M22959216G3QD",
       "message" => "name:\"sandeep kanabar\"",
        "status" => "Both name and surname present"
}
```

Comment: thanks @Sandeep Kanabar for the details clarification.